# How to use SQL Server AT TIME ZONE clause with JPQL?

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have to convert date fields in *where* clause of query from one time zone(server time zone) to another (client time zone). I am able to achieve this for MySQL database using **CONVERT_TZ** function, but for Microsoft SQL Server, AT TIME ZONE clause throwing error in below JPQL.

```
select (PR.requestDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Time' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'),count(*)  FROM com.grc.pam.model.entity.PrivilegeRequest PR  where 1 = 1  and (PR.requestDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Time' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time') >= ?1  and (PR.requestDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Time' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time') < ?2  GROUP BY (PR.requestDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Time' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time')
```

**Error:**

```
18:13:50.006 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:24: unexpected token: AT
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: AT at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expressionOrVector(HqlBaseParser.java:5226) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
```

Does this **AT TIME ZONE**  clause works in JPQL? or is there any other way to achieve this?

**Update:**

Query with `CONVERT` funtion:

```
select (CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'),count(*)  FROM com.grc.pam.model.entity.PrivilegeRequest PR  where 1 = 1  and (CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time') >= ?1  and (CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time') < ?2  GROUP BY (CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time')
```

**Error:**

```
14:23:06.303 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:46: unexpected 
token: AT
14:23:06.319 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:46: unexpected 
token: AT
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: AT


Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: AT near line 1, column 46 [select 
(CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard 
Time'),count(*)  FROM com.grc.pam.model.entity.PrivilegeRequest PR  
where 1 = 1  and (CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME ZONE 
'India Standard Time') >= ?1  and 
(CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard 
Time') < ?2  GROUP BY (CONVERT(datetime,PR.requestDate,120) AT TIME 
ZONE 'India Standard Time')]
```

Comment: Don't you need just one `AT TIME ZONE …`? The time stored (in an unknown type) should be in the source zone and you can express it in another zone with `AT TIME ZONE`. That would explain the error message `unexpected token: AT`…

Comment: @deHaar, tested with one AT TIME ZONE with native query, but date is not being converted, but it is with two AT TIME ZONE . I read somewhere that first it converts the date to source time zone and from that it converts to target time zone. However, I will try with one in JPQL.

Comment: That's because your query is entirely missing the required `CONVERT(type, value, 126) AT TIME ZONE …`, see examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: It is still same even after using `CONVERT(type, value, 126) AT TIME ZONE`. Question is updated with query with `CONVERT` and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After did some research on this, found that we can not call/use this SQL Server *"AT TIME ZONE*" clause directly in JPQL.

As explained in [MetadataBuilderContributor](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/), used  `MetadataBuilderContributor` utility to customize the `MetadataBuilder` like below:

```
public class SqlTimeZoneMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

@Override
public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("CONVERT_TIMEZONE", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP,
            "CONVERT(datetime, ?1 AT TIME ZONE ?2 AT TIME ZONE ?3)"));

}
```

}

Specified this to `jpaProperties` property of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` as property.

```
<prop key="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor">com.grc.common.SqlTimeZoneMetadataBuilderContributor</prop>
```

**Usage in JPQL:**

```
and (CONVERT_TIMEZONE(PR.requestDate, '"+serverDisplayName+"', '"+clientDisplayName+"')) >= ?
```